# Why can the $n_{\epsilon}$ of the definitions of convergence and Cauchy sequence be the same in the following proposition?

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

I have the following proposition proved in my lectures notes, but I think there are a couple of errors and there is one think I don't get:

If $p_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in a metric space $(X,d)$, the set $\{p_n| n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is bounded. Moreover, if $p_n$ has $p_0$ as a limit point, then $p_n$ converges to $p_0$  **----->(1)**

Proof

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Now for each $n \geq n_{\epsilon}$, $d(p_n, p_{n_{\epsilon}}) < \epsilon$. Then $p_n \in B_d(p_{n_{\epsilon}}, \epsilon)$ for each $n\geq n_{\epsilon}$, from which the thesis follows.
Moreover, if $p_0$ is the limit of subsequence $p_{n_k}$, for  $\epsilon >0$, there exists $n_{\epsilon}$ such that $d(p_{n_k},p_0)< \epsilon/2$ and  $d(p_{n_k},p_n)< \epsilon/2$ for $n\geq n_{\epsilon}$ and $k\geq n_{\epsilon}$. **----->(2)**

Then,

$d(p_n,p_0) \leq d(p_n,p_{n_k})+d(p_{n_k},p_0) < \epsilon$ for $n, k \geq n_{\epsilon}$
**----->(3)**

from which the thesis follows

**I think there are some errors in this proof. I would like some feedback/confirmation on it**

(1) --> it should say " if **$p_{n_k}$** has $p_0$ as a limit point" instead of " if **$p_{n}$** has $p_0$ as a limit point"

(2), (3),  it should be $n_k \geq n_{\epsilon}$, instead of $k \geq n_{\epsilon}$

**And a small question that is really bothering me :**

For all $\epsilon > 0$, If $p_n$ is a Cauchy sequence, the definition  says an $n_{\epsilon}$ exist , such that for all $n_1, n_2 >n_{\epsilon}$  $d(p_{n_1},p_{n_2})<\epsilon$.

The definition of convergence says: If $p_n$ converges to $p_0$, then for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exist and $n_{\epsilon}$, such that for any $n > n_{\epsilon}$, $d(p_n, p_{n_{\epsilon}})<\epsilon$.

When they mix the definitions to prove the second part of the proposition, the one about the subsequence, they consider the $\epsilon$ and the $n_{\epsilon} $ of both definitions to be the same. I agree for the  $\epsilon$, because since it must be true for all $\epsilon $ I can choose them to be equal, but then what guarantees that the $n_{\epsilon} $ of the first definition is the same as the $n_{\epsilon} $ of the second definition ? The definitions just state some $n_{\epsilon} $ exists. It is assumed they are equal without saying why and I really can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wording ‘if $p_n$ has $p_0$ as a limit point’ is very sloppy, but not for the reason that you suggest at (1). It’s sloppy because $p_n$ is a single point, not a sequence; what the author means is ‘if $\langle p_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ has $p_0$ as a limit point’ (in which any other standard notation for a sequence can be substituted for my preferred notation). What the author means here, however, is correct: if the original Cauchy sequence has $p_0$ as a limit point (I would say *cluster point*), then it converges to $p_0$. Not only is your suggestion not what he’s trying to say, it would make no sense: no subsequence $\langle p_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ has even been defined at that point.

There is also nothing wrong with $k\ge n_\epsilon$ at (2) and (3), though it would have been helpful if the author had explained why this is the case. The point is that since $\langle p_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a subsequence of $\langle p_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$, the sequence $\langle n_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a strictly increasing sequence of natural numbers, and it’s easy to prove by induction on $k$ that this implies that $n_k\ge k$ for each $k\in\Bbb N$. Thus, $k\ge n_\epsilon$ immediately implies that $n_k\ge n_\epsilon$.

The definition of convergence in the penultimate paragraph of your question is incorrect. It should read:

> $\langle p_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $p_0$ if and only if for each $\epsilon>0$ there is an $n_\epsilon\in\Bbb N$ such that for each $n>n_\epsilon$, $d(p_n,\color{red}{p_0})<\epsilon$.

The last part of the proof is correct, but the author has omitted a little explanation. There is an $m_\epsilon\in\Bbb N$ such that $d(p_{n_k},p_0)<\frac{\epsilon}2$ whenever $k\ge m_\epsilon$. There is a possibly different $m_\epsilon'\in\Bbb N$ such that $d(p_{n_k},p_n)<\frac{\epsilon}2$ whenever $k,n\ge m_\epsilon'$. Now let $n_\epsilon=\max\{m_\epsilon,m_\epsilon'\}$, then $d(p_{n_k},p_0)<\frac{\epsilon}2$ **and** $d(p_{n_k},p_n)<\frac{\epsilon}2$ whenever $k,n\ge m_\epsilon'$, and we’re home free.

Comment: Allow me to use an example in the more familiar space of real numbers with the usual metric . Then saying that a sequence ${p_n}$ converges to $p_0$ is by definition the same as saying that the limit is $p_0$, isn't it? So I thought here was the same , and  that stating that as something to prove was wrong and therefore that the author referred to subsequences instead. The term "limit point" is the first time I hear it, but I thought it was just wording for saying "limit" , so they are not the same, then?

Comment: Because the author started using the definition of convergence for a subsequence right off the bat, I thought that  the correct thesis that   was to prove that if a subsequence of a Cauchy sequence has limit $p_0$, then that was the limit of the whole sequence,as happens in the reals, where Cauchy sequences and convergent sequences imply each other

Comment: @J.C.VegaO: That’s why I prefer the term *cluster point*: a point $x$ is a cluster point of a sequence $\sigma=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ if some subsequence of $\sigma$ converges to $x$. Many people, apparently including your author, use the term *limit point* for this concept and distinguish between ‘$x$ is **a limit point** of $\sigma$’ and ‘$\sigma$ converges to the limit $p$’ or, more confusingly, ‘$p$ is **the limit** of the sequence $\sigma$’.

Comment: @J.C.VegaO: The proposition **is** that if a Cauchy sequence $\sigma$ has a subsequence converging to $p$, then $\sigma$ converges to $p$. You simply didn’t realize that ‘if $\sigma$ has $p$ as a limit point’ actually means simply that $\sigma$ has a subsequence converging to $p$.

Comment: According to what I am reading about limit points in metric spaces if a sequence is convergent it has only one limit point an that coincides with the limit of the sequence?

Comment: And what fdo you thing about the use of the same $n_\epsilon$ when mixing definitions, You used different ones and took the max which is clearer, but I've seen many proofs around that just take them as equal, which looks kind of wrong,...why  is that?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO: Yes, in any metric space (in fact in any Hausdorff space) a convergent sequence has only one limit (or cluster) point and converges to that point. As for the second point, if you look closely, you’ll see that those proofs, like the one here, actually just say that there is an $n_\epsilon$ that does both jobs; they expect the reader to recognize that if you start with different ones for the two jobs, the larger will do nicely for both. It’s not wrong; it’s just an example of the writer expecting the reader to fill in small steps.

Answer (score 0):

Why not say : suppose $(p_n)$ is Cauchy. Then apply the definition of Cauchy-ness to $\varepsilon=1$ and we find $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$\forall n,m \ge N: d(p_n, p_m) < 1$$

So we define $$M=\max\{d(p_1, p_N), \ldots, d(p_{N_1}, p_N)\}+1$$

and we have that $$\{p_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\} \subseteq B(p_N, M)$$

and so the range of the sequence is bounded.

If moreover $p_0$ is a limit point of $\{p_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Then in fact $p_n \to p_0$ as well: let $\varepsilon >0$. We find $N_1$ (from the Cauchy definition applied to $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}>0$) such that

$$\forall n,m \ge N_1: d(p_n, p_m) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}  .$$

As $p_0$ is a limit point of the range, $B(p_0, \frac{\varepsilon}{2})$ contains infinitely many $p_n$ (i.e. for infinitely many indices). So pick $p_k \in B(p_0, \frac{\varepsilon}{2})$ with $k \ge N_1$.

And then for $n \ge N_1$ we have

$$d(p_n,p_0) \le d(p_n, p_k) + d(p_k, p_0) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon$$

and as we found such $N_1$ for arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$, $p_n \to p_0$ as promised.

Comment: Isn't saying that a sequence has a limit point and that it converges to that point just different wording for exactly the same thing?. That is why I believed there is something wrong in the proposition and that it should refer to a subsequence rather than to the sequence

Comment: @J.C.VegaO a limit point of $\{p_n\mid n\}$ and a limit of a subsequence aren’t always the same. You cited question talked about the former, and subsequences aren’t really necessary. We *can* also prove that for a Cauchy sequence a subsequence limit is a total limit too.